# 2 enumerate side by side continuing on next page

Tags: enumerate, multicol, sidebyside

I want to have 2 enumeration syde by syde continuing in the next page.

Here is an example code of what I have:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[4]

\begin{multicols}{2}


    \centering{\textbf{Part 1}}
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left,start=2, label=\textbf{Step \arabic*:}]
        \item bla bla bla bla
        \item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

        \item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

        \item bla bla bla bla

        \item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

        \item bla bla bla bla
    \end{enumerate}
    \columnbreak
        \centering{\textbf{Part 2}}
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left,start=2, label=\textbf{Step \arabic*:}]
    \item bla bla bla bla
    \item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

    \item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

    \item bla bla bla bla

    \item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

    \item bla bla bla bla
    \end{enumerate}



    \end{multicols}

    \end{document}
```

The following figure shows what happens:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

How can I do it in LaTeX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paracol` package can be used for this. MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{paracol}{2}
\centering\textbf{Part 1}\\
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,start=2, label=\textbf{Step \arabic*:}, itemsep=5pt]
\item abc def
\item bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\switchcolumn
\centering\textbf{Part 2}\\
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,start=2, label=\textbf{Step \arabic*:}]
\item nom nom nom nom
\item nom nom nom nom nom nom nom nom nom nom nom nom
\item nom nom nom nom nom nom nom nom
\item nom nom nom nom
\item nom nom nom nom nom nom nom nom
\item nom nom nom nom
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]